# YouTube API to upload 3D-360 videos

Tags: android, youtube-api, 360-virtual-reality

I'm told the YouTube devs watch this tag. I found some old posts about this, but looks like no updates since at least Sep 2015. I know that sometimes this is because the issue is addressed and the thread abandoned. In case it's not:

Is there a way to upload a video to YouTube via API (like, from an Android phone app) such that, it being a 360 over-under 3D clip (or still), shows up on YouTube as such?

Answer (score 0):

Youtube API doesn't support uploading of 360 videos yet. Try to file a request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request).

You can still upload using the manual way which is mentioned in [Upload 360-degree videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6178631?hl=en).